# App Crashes Only On Testflight Build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have created an app on swift and tested it extensively using iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 5 devices and all the simulators offered in Xcode. The app runs fine and does not crash when uploaded locally. (iOS 8)

I finally submitted a build for Testflight. The app consistently crashes at the same place after downloading the app through the Testflight build.

Is there a known issue where uploaded builds run differently than locally created builds? And how can I debug the issue with the Testflight build?

Comment: Had the same issue once. I deleted the app on my device and reinstalled it. That helped. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I deleted everything and even wiped one of my devices. On all devices that download the app using Testflight, it crashes at the same place. When I install the build locally (through Xcode), it never crashes.

Comment: If the app crashes while using it, then you have a bug in your code. You need to provide a symbolicated crash report for others to be able to provide hints on what is happening.

Comment: But I cannot replicate this code unless the app is downloaded through Testflight. Is it possible to debug the Testflight build in Xcode (using break points etc.)?

Comment: When it doesn't crash, are you in debug mode vs not in debug mode with Testflight?

Comment: When the app crashes, it generates a crash report on the device. Connect the device after the crash to Xcode, open "Devices" window and check the devices crash reports and the console to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the swift compiler optimization from `fastest` to `none`. I'm not sure if this is an ideal long term solution, but the build no longer crashes.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I first tried changing the Bitcode setting to No but it was not solved. Next, I changed the optimization to none. This time the app did not crash. So I'm sticking to this solution @loop Have you found if this is the ideal solution or not?

Comment: In my version of VS for Mac, I unchecked "Enable Optimizations" under Build->Compiler and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 90):

I guess its a swift compiler issue. To verify first go to **Edit Scheme** then change the **Build configuration** to **Release** mode in **Run** tab and then install the build locally. You will get to know where exactly its crashing.

Comment: I actually solved the issue by changing the swift compiler optimization from fastest to none. I'm not sure if this is an ideal long term solution, but the builds no longer crash.

Comment: Same problem here. How do you change “swift compiler optimization”?

Comment: 1)Build Settings
2)Swift Compiler - Code Generation
3)Optimization Level

Comment: I had a similar issue. Using release configuration in the scheme pinpointed the crash for me and made me realise my mistake: I used the DEBUG flag to only run some code while developing. Not running the piece of debug code put my app in the wrong state and the crash occured.... Shame on me, much thanks for your tip!

Comment: @Taylor you should create an answer with how you solved it and mark it as  correct

Comment: I did this and am getting an `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=1, subcode=0x0)` error...

Comment: How can you test on a device after changing to Release mode?

Comment: This does not help because problem is only with build used via test flight. Debug and also release build installed via Xcode is not crashing.

Answer (score 14):

In my case this happened after starting to use Xcode 11. It was a `UISearchDisplayController` (deprecated since iOS 8) that seems to work on a device or simulator in debug mode, but not in the release build. Xcode 11.3 doesn't give any inline warning in the code.
The crash was hard to find, because the search controller wasn't used any more, it was orphaned code.

Comment: God bless you! The old UISearchDisplayController was still linked in my Storyboard file..

Comment: @Kian same here. I wonder why it works in Debug build but not in Release?

Comment: Yeah it really doesn’t make any sense

Comment: @brainray how could we check, or where is that, do u mind explain step by step, thanks

Comment: @brainray You probably mean: I wonder why it works in Debug and also in Release but does not work only via testflight? Btw can you explain please step by step where I can change UISearchDisplayController?

Comment: Thank you! You save me who knows how long. I initially removed the code, but that didn't help. It took me a while to find all the references in the crowd. It is important to remove ALL references.

Answer (score 7):

It might be the **Bitcode** related issue. Check if your all third-party libraries support bitcode then and then only set bitcode to **YES** else set to **NO**.

Actually Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store.

Comment: How do you check to see if all libraries support bitcode?

Comment: @Honey did you figure out how we could check Bitcode, so frustrating , i dont have any error, simulator works fine, but at testFlight i am seeing black screen after splash page :(

Answer (score 7):

For all those who face this similar issue, can follow these steps

Go to **Xcode->widows->organiser** then select **crashes** tab then select your app.
If you have added your apple account in **Xcode->preferences-> accounts** then you Xcode will download all crash reports even for the testflight build.

It will have the stack trace you don't need to symbloicate it like old times.
PS:- the most common which I have seen is UISearchDisplayController issue

Comment: For me , saying no crash report? is there any way to active reports??

Comment: @greenridinghood If your apple developer account is added in Xcode and is same as the one used in test flight then you should get crash logs. It might happen that the tester at times might choose do not send crash report. It is prompted after crash in test flight build

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still having this issue working with React Native, you can run this command to run it in release mode, the same when you archive a build. That way you can debug the issue easier:

```
react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, changing Legacy Build System to New Build System (for Xcode 10) solves my issue where Testflight build behaves differently. Might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

I got it (partially!). Actually "release" implementation of UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() in swift project crashes the app.

However, still I have no clue why our app store app (objective c language based) does NOT crash.

My only guess is that it's a glitch in UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() API implementation with some language specific coding (swift vs objective c) by Apple.

Anyways, I would replace all UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() with UIDevice(). userInterfaceIdiom. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having the same problem, here's what my fix was:

I finally got the problem down to a loop with a if statement, akin to this -

```
while(condition)
{
    if (check)
    {
        code!
    }
    //There was no code here
}
```

Notice that there's no code at the end of the loop (where the comment is).  Once I added a random bit of code (in this case, incrementing a variable for output), **the problem stopped.**

```
while(condition)
{
    if (check)
    {
        code!
    }
    i += 1;
    output statement
}
```

I think this has to be a compiler error, or else my "fix" shouldn't be a fix at all.  But here it is in case it helps anyone else!

Comment: Not very useful... you should have cleaned it and then re-run than this redundant coding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `i += 1;` in the empty while loops.

I did this in my empty while Loop: `RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1))`

And now the TestFlight App does not bomb!

A shorter time might also work such as: `RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.25))`

Answer (score 0):

Release build actually takes a different entitlement file than debug build entitlement while debugging in local.

While uploading an archive build it will take release build settings and release entitlement file by default. Make sure you have all the release settings correctly edited in the configurations.