# App getting crash only for testflight build but working fine with development or adhoc build

Tags: ios9, xcode7, testflight

I am getting this error only in testflight app store build. If I run app from xcode or prepare a adhoc build then app works well. but if I submit to app store and install via testflight feature of app store then app gets crash on app launch.

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 1 
beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I had try following from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570444/app-crashes-only-on-testflight-build):
To verify first go to Edit Scheme then change the Build configuration to Release mode in Run tab and then install the build locally.