# App crash on ios 9.2.1 via TestFlight

Tags: crash, testflight, ios9.2.1

I develop the app and testing on iphone 7 ios 10 and iphone 6+ ios 9.2.1. If i testing wia xcode (debug/release) all fine. If i testing wia testflight ios 9.2.1 app crashes every time at random time. Crash log show me absolutly difference reason at every crash

Comment: This could be a compiler issue. Is your app written in Swift? If so you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570444/app-crashes-only-on-testflight-build

Comment: Yes, app written in swift 3, but crash only at ios 9.2.1 and testflight

Comment: This solution dont help me, and other solution with compile optimization also dont help. Its like a magic.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404285/xcode-8-build-crash-on-ios-9-2-and-below