# Error: signal SIGABRT only occurs in Release Mode Xcode React Native

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

My app works fine in debug mode but after submitting to TestFlight and trying to launch the app it crashes with no explanation whatsoever.

Someone suggested that I build my app in **Release mode** to see where the error comes from and I'm now getting the following error:

> ->  0x10f2cbd42 <+10>: jae    0x10f2cbd4c               ; <+20>
>
> signal SIGABRT

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try to run react-native link if you haven't already please

Comment: @Marco Ok so I tried react-native link one more time, it built all assets successfully but still getting the same error in release mode.. I even tried to Product > Clean but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that can be wrong in this case.

Try to get a stack trace to see whats wrong.

You can do that by:

- running your app in the release build configuration from Xcode.
- adding the Crashlytics SDK to your app and run your app from TestFlight. 
  The stack trace will appear inside the Fabric console.

Comment: But how can I view more information about this issue with the basic Xcode functionalities ?

Comment: And how can O install Crashhylics with ReactNative ?

Comment: Here you can find a detailed explanation about how to setup Crashlytics in your app https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Comment: try this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570444/app-crashes-only-on-testflight-build?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to tracking user without asking permission