# iOS cordova app crashes at the TestFlight build not same for the DEBUG builds

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios14, cordova-ios

Currently, I am working on the hybrid application using Cordova, the app was working fine till iOS 13 version on both locally and Test flight builds. But after releasing iOS 14 version, we tested the same app on the iOS 14 version and has been observed multiple crashes on different screens. We tested the same build is working fine on locally / debug version on iOS 14 but the crashes happening only on release builds both Test flight as well as Ad-hoc export IPA version.

Here is the current project configuration -

Cordova-iOS version : 5.1.1
Minimum deployment iOS : 10.0.0
Cordova version : 10.0.0

**I tried few things to fixing the crash issue -**

1. Changing the preference flags for WebView and WebView engine in config.xml file.
2. Changing the schema, running the build in release version not able to get the logs or the issues causing the crash.
3. Changing the Swift compiler optimisation level to fastest to none by following the link - [App Crashes Only On Testflight Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570444/app-crashes-only-on-testflight-build).

Note - Thanks for suggestions on upgrading the Cordova-iOS version to latest we are already in the process of upgrading the cordova-iOS version to 6.2.0 with some additional features in the app. But for current version market release need to immediate and quick fix for the crash issue on iOS 14.

Here is the few logs observed in the OS console for release builds at the time of crash -

- [pageID=0, frameID=0, main=0] FrameLoader::continueLoadAfterNavigationPolicy: can't continue loading frame due to the following reasons (allowNavigationToInvalidURL = 0, requestURLIsValid = 0, navigationPolicyDecision = 1)

0x10ff32700 - [pageID=0, frameID=0, frameLoader=0x1095f8190, resourceID=0] SubresourceLoader::willSendRequestInternal: redirect response is NULL.